# Получить права папки у конкретного пользователя

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Как можно получить права доступа у конкретного пользователя к конкретной папке: Права:

- R - read
- W - write
- C - change
- FC - full control
- RW - read and write
- L - list(просмотр папок)
- RO - read only

Пока дошёл до этого, но не понимаю, какие биты получать из переменной типа *ACCESS_MASK*:

```
HANDLE result = CreateFile(LR"(C:\Users\admin_test\Desktop\test\)", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
if (result != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;

PSID pSidOwner = NULL;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
PACL ppDacl = NULL;

SECURITY_INFORMATION ssi = DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION;
GetSecurityInfo(result, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &pSidOwner,
    NULL,
    &ppDacl,
    NULL,
    &pSD);

TRUSTEE trust;
BuildTrusteeWithName(&trust, LPWSTR(L"admin_test"));
ACCESS_MASK rights = 0;
auto err = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(ppDacl, &trust, &rights);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Константы перечислены здесь: [File and Directory Access Rights Constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/file-and-directory-access-rights-constants)

Пользоваться ими нужно примерно так:

```
void PrintAccessRights(ACCESS_MASK Mask)
{
    if (((Mask & GENERIC_READ) == GENERIC_READ) || ((Mask & FILE_GENERIC_READ) == FILE_GENERIC_READ))
        wprintf(L"Read; ");
    if (((Mask & GENERIC_WRITE) == GENERIC_WRITE) || ((Mask & FILE_GENERIC_WRITE) == FILE_GENERIC_WRITE))
        wprintf(L"Write; ");
    if (((Mask & GENERIC_EXECUTE) == GENERIC_EXECUTE) || ((Mask & FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE) == FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE))
        wprintf(L"Execute; ");
    if ((Mask & FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY) == FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY )
        wprintf(L"List directory; ");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Однако, с простыми правами понятно, а как определить "Полный доступ" ? Это комбинация всех флагов?

Comment: @Range `FILE_ALL_ACCESS`